# Threejs Pointlights bleed through Objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, light, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to make a UFO ship with a Spotlight in the middle and 8 pointlights around it as you can see in the figure. I think I got most of the set up correct, but I'm having a hard time preventing the Pointlights from bleeding into the cabin (sphere cap on top).

For context UFO is a class which extends object3d and has added to itself Meshes for cabin, ship (the flattened sphere disk), Open ended Cylinder at the bottom. On the under side it has a Spotlight in the center and an object from another class UFO_Lights which has the 8 tiny spheres and Pointlights.

The Pointlights are pretty much default aside from intensity and range. I haven't touched the shadow camera and I'm wondering if that's the issue. Any tips are greatly appreciated. If needed I can share a bit of the code, though I'd prefer not to since this is a class project.

[image: UFO Angle 1]

[image: UFO Angle 2]

Comment: can you set up SpotLightHelper and PointLightHelper for all lighting for easily reference?

Comment: What do you mean? They are visible in the photos